# How to find basis of vector space with respect to which restriction of linear map is a Jordan block?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I am working on the following Algebra past paper problem:

Let $U$ be the complex vector space of polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ of degree at most 6.  Define $D$, $T:U \rightarrow U$ by $D(f) = f'$ and $T = D^2 + D^3.$ Put

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
V = \text{Span}\{T^nx^6 \mid n\geq 0 \}, \\
W = \text{Span}\{T^nx^5 \mid n\geq 0 \}. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Find a basis of $V$ with respect to which the matrix of $T|_V$ is a Jordan block.  Likewise for $W$.

**My work so far:**

First, note that a previous part of the problem required me to prove that $T(V) \subset V$, which I believe I have done.

I subsequently noticed that $\{T^nx^6 \mid n\geq 4 \}$ is simply equal to the set containing the zero vector.
I also noticed that the four vectors in the set $\{T^nx^6 \mid 0 \leq n \leq 3 \}$ are linearly independent.  These vectors are:

$$
\begin{align}
T^0x^6 &= x^6 \\
T^1x^6 &= 30x^4 + 120x^3 \\
T^2x^6 &= 360(x^2 + 4x + 2) \\
T^3x^6 &= 720 \\
\end{align}
$$

Seeing as $\text{Span}\{T^nx^6 \mid 0 \leq n \leq 3 \} = \text{Span}\{T^nx^6 \mid 0 \leq n \leq 4 \} = V$, it follows that

$$
B_1 = \{T^nx^6 \mid 0 \leq n \leq 3 \}
$$

is a basis of $V$.

I then computed the matrix of $T|_V$ with respect to $B_1$ (recall that this is a basis of $V$) and $B_U = \{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^6 \}$ (the standard basis of $U$):

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 720 & 720 & 0 \\
0 & 1440 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 360 & 0 & 0 \\
120 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
30 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However, this matrix is not a Jordan block, as the problem requires.

I am not sure how to further progress with the problem and would appreciate any **hints and/or corrections**!